# Monopoly - Rent Not Being Transferred To Other Players

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make Monopoly in C#, however, I am facing an unknown issue with the rent. The program should add the prescribed rent to one player and deduct it from the others, but this only works sometimes. The other times, the amount of money each player has remains the same.

```
if (type[roll] == "Land")
{
    if (owned[roll] == "Unowned")
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("You have landed on " + name[roll] + ". This property costs $" + cost[roll] + ". Would you like to purchase it?", "Purchase Property?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            int deduct = Convert.ToInt32(cost[roll]);
            if (player == true)
            {
                money1 -= deduct;
                p1owned[roll] = "Owned";
            }
            else if (player == false)
            {
                money2 -= deduct;
                p2owned[roll] = "False";
            }
            parking += deduct;
            owned[roll] = "Owned";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (player == true && p2owned[roll] == "Owned")
        {
            money2 += Convert.ToInt32(rent[roll]);
            money1 -= Convert.ToInt32(rent[roll]);
        }
        else if (player == false && p1owned[roll] == "Owned")
        {
            money1 += Convert.ToInt32(rent[roll]);
            money2 -= Convert.ToInt32(rent[roll]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the variable player pertain to in this scenario?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the beginning of your else block and debug.

Comment: What is `player`, `money1`, `money2`, `roll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're checking to see which player landed on the property, and then subtracting the `deduct` amount from the appropriate account. If that's right, then the problem is here:

```
if (player == true)
{
  money1 -= deduct;
  p1owned[roll] = "Owned";
}
else if (player == false)
{
  money2 -= deduct;
  p2owned[roll] = "False";
}
```

You'll notice that the state of p2owned[roll] gets set to "False" instead of "Owned". This is why you should factor out common code into methods: if you decide to change an implementation detail, you only have to change it in one place.

Comment: I disagree with the final recommendation.  A much better solution would be to use an enumeration, not strings.  Then it won't be possible to assign an unhandled value.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Great suggestion. I don't think I would go about this problem this way at all, but OP can get moving in the right direction now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exact rules of Monopoly, but I suggest you to take a look on Object-Oriented programming. Instead of keeping all data in arrays `type`, `owned`, `cost`, `p1owned`, `p2owned`, etc use objects to group related data together. E.g. you can create class `Property` which will hold property name, cost, rent and owner:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Rent { get; set; }
    public Player Owner { get; set; }
    public bool IsOwned { get { return Owner != null; } }
}
```

But OOP is not just about grouping related data together - you can (and should) put behavior related to that data in same object. Here is sample of `Player` class, which holds his owned properties, and manages buying and paying rent:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Money { get; set; }        

    public void Buy(Property property)
    {
        // TODO: Handle (property.Price > Money) case
        Money -= property.Price;
        property.Owner = this;            
    }

    public void PayRent(Property property)
    {
        // TODO: Handle (property.Rent > Money) case
        Money -= property.Rent;
        property.Owner.Money += property.Rent;
    }
}
```

Now all your code above can be written in more readable fashion:

```
// get rolled property
var property = properties[rolled];

if (property.IsOwned)
{
    if (currentPlayer == property.Owner)
        return;

    currentPlayer.PayRent(property);
    return;
}

if (!PlayerWantsToPurchase(property)) // definition of method is below
    return;

currentPlayer.Buy(property);
```

Isn't this code looks almost like plain English text?

```
private bool PlayerWantsToPurchase(Property property)
{
   var message = String.Format("You have landed on {0}. This property costs ${1}. Would you like to purchase it?", 
                               property.Name, property.Price);

   var result = MessageBox.Show(message, "Purchase Property?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
   return result == DialogResult.Yes;
}
```